# Django view not working for project

Tags: python, django

Context:
I am creating a website to house some webcomics I made as a project to practice Django. I am adapting Django's tutorial to create the site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/ About halfway down the page under "Write views that actually do something"). I am having some difficulty getting part of my view to work as expected.

Expectation:
What I see when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/futureFleet/ : latest_comic

What I want to see: A dictionary of my 2 comics.

Question:
I think I am doing something wrong at this line

context = {'latest_comic': latest_comic}. I am adapting this line from the tutorial.  What do I do? What am I missing?

Models.py

```
class Comic(models.Model):
    #title
    comic_title_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #date
    comic_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('comic date published')
    #image
    comic_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #explanation
    comic_explanation_text = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comic_title_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.comic_pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_comic = Comic.objects.order_by('-comic_pub_date')[:2]
    context = {'latest_comic': latest_comic}
    return HttpResponse(context)
    # return render(request, 'futureFleet/index.html', context) This sends to the template but doesn’t work at the moment
```

Database

```
"Welcome Aboard" "2018-01-15 21:02:54" "/home/user/Desktop/django/djangoFutureFleet/mysite/futureFleet/static/futureFleet/images/1.JPG" "this is the first comic"

"Space Vaccine" "2018-01-15 23:02:22" "/home/user/Desktop/django/djangoFutureFleet/mysite/futureFleet/static/futureFleet/images/2.JPG" "This is comic 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
Comic.objects.order_by('-comic_pub_date')[:2]
```

You are asking Django for all `Comic` objects sorted by publication date. You then take the first two with `[:2]`. Here's a simple example of this syntax:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> print(a[:2])
[0, 1]
```

What you're probably looking for is:

```
Comic.objects.order_by('-comic_pub_date').first()
```

That would only return the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the view to your urls.py? In order to access the view, you need to connect it to a URL. In your urls.py file, add
`path('/',<your app name>.views.index),`
or if you're using the old django:
`url(r'', <your app name>.views.index),`

After that, try this:

```
latest_comic = Comic.objects.all().order_by('-comic_pub_date')[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def index(request):
    latest_comic = Comic.objects.order_by('-comic_pub_date')[:2]
    dictionary = {'comic_1':latest_comic[0], 'comic_2':latest_comic[1]}
    return HttpResponse(dictionary)
```

Note: `latest_comic[0]`
will return the first field value of the model, in your case: `Welcome Aboard`

If you want to access other fields you will need to do the following:

```
latest_comic[0].field_name
```